# My Terminal won't download requests and discord.py

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-requests, discord.py

I'm using Visual Studio Code to make a discord bot sent notification. I need discord.py and requests installed but when I install them, and do pip list, I don't see them. I saw discord.py installed and then when I did pip install requests, it was gone. I'm using Python 3.11 and most recent version of Visual Studio Code. When I try to install discord.py, it states, "Requirement already satisfied." Any help is greatly appreciated!

I tried using ChatGPT, but nothing has happened, as stated, I kept trying to install, but nothing.

(I recently started using Visual Studio Code if that changes anything.)

Comment: show exactly what commands you are using.

Comment: Commands I am using are:

pip install discord.py
pip install requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go into terminal (open a fresh window - DO NOT type python first)
2. Type `pip install requests`

   `pip install dicord.py`
3. Enter

Comment: I did pip list and saw that they are not installed. Thank you so much.

Quick question: I have the file of a code I want to run, can I type that command in the new window's terminal or in the window with the code?

Comment: @Mod this solved your problem? But isn't it telling you to do what you just told me that you already did?

Comment: It wasn't popping up, and apparently on a new window, it just showed up.